# Dynamic add marker cluster on google map

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to dynamically add markers on map and cluster them using markerCluster
like the link below: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/examples.html
The scenario is , when users get into my website, they will see an initial google map, 
and when they press the button, I'll go back to my database to get 100 data and draw on map for users
because 100 data is kind of big on may especially they are close, so I want to use markerCluster, but somehow it didn't work and I can't find out why, there is no error show in console(I use chrome's web developer tools)

here is my javascript, I use java, javascript and jsp:

```
$('#addMarkerData').click(function(){
console.log('into addMarkerData click function');
$.get('getphoto.do',{},function(Result){
    var markers = [];
    var image = 'img/location.png';
    for(var i=0; i < 100; i++){
            console.log(Result[i].photoId);
            console.log(Result[i].latitude);
            console.log(Result[i].longitude);
            console.log(Result[i].imgURL);  
              var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(Result[i].latitude,
                      Result[i].longitude);
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                  position: latLng,
                  icon: image
              });
              markers.push(marker);
    }
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
    console.log(markerCluster.getTotalMarkers());
});
```

});

The variable map is declare on another .js files, and will be loaded before this .js files

one more thing, the last line in my code, `console.log(markerCluster.getTotalMarkers())` show the correct answer (100) ,btw

it would be very appreciated if anyone could give me some advice 
thanks

Comment: when you put a `console.log(map)` into the get-callback, what do you see?

Comment: I saw this:
http://d.pr/i/lzZX

Answer (score 5):

You should create `MarkerClusterer` outside the function so that you can use it over and over. You could create it immediately after creating the map:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map();
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map);
```

You can then use the `addMarker()` or `addMarkers()` method inside your JSON callbacks. The same marker clusterer will be used each time so any previously added markers will not be deleted. Rough outline of the code:

```
$('#addMarkerData').click(function () {
    $.get('getphoto.do', {}, function (Result) {
        var markers = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < Result.length; i++) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(Result[i].latitude, Result[i].longitude),
                icon: 'img/location.png'
            });
            markers.push(marker);
        }
        markerCluster.addMarkers(markers);
        console.log(markerCluster.getTotalMarkers());
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your advice, however it still doesn't work, this is my console log in my $.get()'s callback function :
http://d.pr/i/lzZX

Comment: Thank you guys, I found the problem... actually I have already done the markcluster work... the reason why I don't saw any marker on map is because I put lat in longitude and put lon in latitude...so when I check my marker's position, it always show latitude on 90...
I think this is one of reason why I can't see markers on the map, thank you again.